# ASP.NET MVC5 DROPDOWNLIST

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, view, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

Can anyone help me with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kxqI.png). The first item on list is always empty , so it shouldn't be like that :

```
@Html.DropDownList("EMRecordType_", null, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Code in controller :

```
ViewBag.EMRecordType_ = new SelectList(db.EMRecords, "EMRecordType_", "EMRecordType_");
```

Comment: Because you have `""` as the 3rd parameter (which generates an option with that text, and a value of `null`). Just remove it - `@Html.DropDownList("EMRecordType_", null, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Now the first element on the list goes up and stays as default value , i want the dropdownlist default value to be empty .

Comment: Yes of course - your not binding to anything by using that overload, and if you do not bind to anything, the first option will always be selected. Its not clear now what you want to do, but that is the worst possible way to generate a dropdownlist. To do it correctly, refer to the code in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your Issue it is working fine

```
@Html.DropDownList("EMRecordType_", null, null, new { @class = "form-control" })


 public ActionResult Demo()
    {
        try
        {
            List<DemoModel> li = new List<Models.DemoModel>()
        {
            new DemoModel { ID = "1" , Value = "DemoModel1"},
            new DemoModel { ID = "2" , Value = "DemoModel2"},
            new DemoModel { ID = "3" , Value = "DemoModel3"},
            new DemoModel { ID = "4" , Value = "DemoModel4"},
            new DemoModel { ID = "5" , Value = "DemoModel5"},
            new DemoModel { ID = "6" , Value = "DemoModel6"},
            new DemoModel { ID = "7" , Value = "DemoModel7"},
        };

            ViewBag.EMRecordType_ = new SelectList(li, "ID", "Value");

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question , i added a screenshot , with this code , the first item list now stands as default value .I want the default value to be SELECT , and on the list to have the items from database .

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("empRecordTypeDropDown", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EMRecordType_, "Please Select", new {@class="form-control"})
 this works fine , but the problem is that when i press arrow , the first element on list is Please Select , then the others , i want to remove this first time ,  nor please select , nor empty first element , ..only the list elements from database

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you wanted to add an empty default value,like "Please Select..." to the drop-down list.

Try this to get the following output..

```
@Html.DropDownList("empRecordTypeDropDown", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EMRecordType_, "Please Select", new {@class="form-control"})
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdETB.png)

If you want to add totally empty option then use

```
@Html.DropDownList("empRecordTypeDropDown", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EMRecordType_, "", new {@class="form-control"})
```

[and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmOdG.png)

- The first parameter takes a not null string value which is used as an `id` and `name`for the drop-down.
- As the `@Html.Dropdown` requires a collection of `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` so you have to cast the dynamic `ViewBag`.

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("empRecordTypeDropDown", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EMRecordType_, "Please Select", new {@class="form-control"})
 this works fine , but the problem is that when i press arrow , the first element on list is Please Select , then the others , i want to remove this first time ,  nor please select , nor empty first element , ..only the list elements from database